# Conda Environment Export: is it possible to make something an optional dependency?

Tags: python, conda, setup.py, virtual-environment, pyproject.toml

## Exporting Conda Environment with Optional Dependencies

I cannot find anything in a Google search or [the Conda environment documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#exporting-an-environment-file-across-platforms) explaining how I can create optional environment dependencies like what is available in [`package.json`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/dependency-types/) in the JS world.

### Need: A Configurable Template

I am making a package that is more like a *template* than a true library, so it makes sense to export the Conda environment instead of embedding it in a `setup.py` or a [`pyproject.toml`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/).  As a template, there are some aspects that need to exist, and some that exist only if you want "all the gadgets".

Is it possible to set optional needs in the Conda environment file?

Comment: See if [this merge request](https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/4982) fulfills your need. Else you'll have to wait for [a different implementation](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7502).

Comment: I think we need some clarification: it sounds like you're talking about a `meta.yaml` for a package you wish to build (a `conda-build` question), but reference "exporting" an environment which only occurs with the end user (a `conda` question). Maybe expand a bit more on how you expect this to be used. Possibly you're looking for [build variants](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/variants.html)?

Comment: @merv, Tin understands me correctly:  that merge request looks like it should handle what I am trying to do.  I will try it and see.  But to your question:  I am looking to make a *template* that we can build future projects off of.  Think of it something like [cookiecutter](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/), but with a conda environment.  Does that help?  I want (a) as "built" as possible, but (b) still configurable.  But in the end, it will be closer to an *app* than a *library*, which is why I prefer exporting an environment file over creating a package.